# Laravel view is not getting session data

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to pass some data to a view and it appears as though the view is not getting it. Here is the getProfile route in my controller:

```
public function getProfile($username)
{
    if(User::userExists($username))
    {
        if($username == Auth::user()->username)
            return View::make('user.profile');
        else
            return View::make('user.profile')->with('user-requested', $username);

}
```

The view is supposed to change based on whether the parameter $username is the user logged in, in which it will display more information and allow editing and if not then limited information will be displayed. I am checking the session 'user-requested' key in my view as follows:

```
Username: {{ Session::get('user-requested'); }}
```

and also like the following:

```
@if(!Session::has('user-requested'))
//display full profile info
@else
//display limited profile info
```

Currently the view just displays the full profile info block regardless of whether I enter a username parameter that is not the currently logged in user. The session variable 'user-requested' seems to be null but I am unsure why, is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Session to get user-requested variable in view, just use it simple something like this.

```
@if(isset($user-requested))

@else

@endif
```

To put data in session you have to use `Session::put('key','value')`. The only way the variables are set in Sessions using `with()` is when they are used with redirects.

Comment: How can I access the variable $user-requested in the view? It's is stating it's undefined

Comment: `{{$user-requested}}` which is just like `<?php echo $user-requested; ?>`